# Adapter Edit text get String value on another activity

Tags: android

I have one scenario like i want open layout from number of adult passenger coming from previous activity. On current Activity i have open list of number passenger details like name,dob  in edit text in adapter using custom adapter. i want to get String value of name, dob on another activity using intent or share preference. Thanks In advance.

Comment: pls explain in detail, it not a clear

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sir , i want to get data without click because it is in adapter to show only data and get value of edit text on another activity from share preference.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

I assume you have RecyclerView and RecyclerViewAdapter class already created, and inside the list of RecyclerView, you want to get any kind of data passed from the list into your next opened activity, right? to do that, inside your adapter view holder class, you could try this:

```js
public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
  TextView textObject;
  public Holder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), YourActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        bundle.putString("string_id", textObject.getText().toString().trim());

        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);

      }
    });
    ...
  }
}
```

And in your destination activity, let's call it YourActivity.class, you can add this code to get extras by adding this code:

```js
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_krs_detail);

  TextView output;

  Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
  output.setText(bundle.getString("string_id"));

  ...

}
```

Correct me if I'm wrong but I didn't understand your question correctly, anyway, I hope this helps.

Cheers.

Comment: sir , i want data without click on it . i want edit text  value on anther activity through share preference which is present in adapter . so please guide me how to do this

Comment: So it means that the adapter you talks about is sharedprefmanager?